# Пропал счетчик на кнопках поделиться

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

у меня код

```
<li class="ya-share">
    <script src="https://yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
    <div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki" data-counter=""></div>
</li>
```

не считает количество шеров, причем когда только поделился статьей - видно один шер (в счетчике добавляется единичка) но после перезагрузки страницы он пропадает

Это можно исправить?